# Cold process to make glass

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, glass

Since glass is a mix of silicates of sodium and calcium produced by heating or fusing together $\ce{Na2O}$ (Lewis base) with sand or $\ce{SiO2}$ (Lewis acid). Since $\ce{Na2O/NaOH(aq)}$ is a strong base and is used to create water glass(es)$(\ce{Na2SiO3},$ $\ce{Na_xSiO_y}$ etc.).

Is there some procedure in place to create glass by mixing (a base rich) water glass at room temperature with calculated amounts of $\ce{CaO}$ in mould to prepare float glass of definite shape without heating or mild heating?

Comment: Bulk materials are not always easily created from the components. For example, is it easy to create bulk iron from iron filings with heating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not glass *per se*, but silica is often produced chemically by [silicon alkoxide gelation](http://www.aerogel.org/?p=16) to create aerogels.

The problem with creating glass by some cold process would be that the reaction side-products, such as water, would have to be removed, leaving holes in a froth of glass. This is fine for creating an aerogel, but is not helpful in making solid objects, such as test tubes or lenses. Of course, you could [sinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintering) the glass frit or froth, but that still requires heating.